# create custom Cell by using core data in swiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui, cell, custom-cell

I want to create a custom Cell for my app with swiftUI and i can't put it in textView. I dont want to use ForEach.

In my core data i have 1 entity: `FacturationCoreData`.
In this entity i have 3 attributes: `Article`, `Price`, `Quantity`.

When I use Text(facture.price), I cant find `price` in attribute in my core data and i have 3 errors:

1.

> Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding' conform to
> 'StringProtocol'

2. 

> Referencing subscript 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' requires wrapper
> 'Binding<FetchRequest.Configuration>'

3. 

> Value of type 'FetchedResults' has no dynamic
> member 'price' using key path from root type
> 'FetchRequest.Configuration'

4.Insert '$'

```
struct FactureRow: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: FacturationCoreData.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) private var factures: FetchedResults<FacturationCoreData>

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            Text(factures.price)
        
            
        }
    }
}

struct FactureRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FactureRow().previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
      
            
    }
}
```

Comment: factures is an array, you need a List or similar to iterate the array and show the content.

Comment: the problem if I use a loop then each time the user puts a text in the textfield then it is added in all the other cells
What is the solution... I have already tried with ObservableObject , StateObject and EnvironmentObject to find a solution but i can t

Comment: That is a different problem and has nothing to do with what I wrote. I see now the view name is FactureRow so judging by the name you shouldn't have a FetchRequest at all but rather pass the FacturationCoreData from another view.

Comment: this is my question how can i do that plz?

Comment: Remove the FetchRequest and add a property for FacturationCoreData, `let facturation: FacturationCoreData`, and then the compiler will generate an error where you need to pass the object to FactureRow.

Comment: Missing argument for parameter 'facturation' in call... what can i put in missing argument . i put  FactureRow(facturation: FacturationCoreData) but got an error --> Cannot convert value of type 'FacturationCoreData.Type' to expected argument type 'FacturationCoreData'

Comment: Well you should be able to figure that out yourself I think. Like I wrote in my previous comment "...pass the _object_"